# Alternative to PDF on iPad

Tags: cocoa-touch, pdf, ios, core-graphics

I have to create a PDF reader for Ipad, so i read about CGPDFdocument and UIWebView. 
In my opinion CGPDFDocument is too complex(i need to mange link) and using a UIWebView i can't customize behavior.

Is there an alternative way to build that? Perhaps a way to convert PDF to another format like ebook ? 
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's hard about CGPDFDocument?  Apple's example in the [Quartz2D programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101) is only 30 lines long.

Comment: Also, it's pretty easy to manage behavior in a UIWebView, so either of the options you mentioned seem viable.

Comment: I find really difficult manage links with CGPDFDocument Am i wrong ?

Comment: Ok i was able to manage pdf with quartz 2d ... JeremyP you were Right, best (and the only one..) answer!